# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.taglib.region.RichDeclarativeComponentTag

Tags: java, rest, oracle-adf

I encounter a problem when I tried to run a simple rest web service.

**Information**:

Java platform: 1.6.0_38

Oracle IDE: 11.1.1.9.40.71.67

Below is the error message:

```
<Apr 18, 2018 7:28:24 PM PDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'lib-RESTWebService-context-root'
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:395)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.taglib.region.RichDeclarativeComponentTag
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I searched a lot but failed to find a solution, could you please give your advice on it?

Thanks!

Comment: You are either missing a library used inside of the code you are executing, or your IDE is misconfigured and missing a library necessary to execute what you are trying to execute. TL/DR: It is missing the class reference of "RichDeclarativeComponentTag" at runtime

Comment: Thank you Joe for your reply. But not sure how to know what's the library is/ define the library? Can anyone provide this information?

Comment: I have added the jar ADF Faces Runtime 11 to the RestWebService but the issue still exists, can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: Compile this shit in eclipse... or InteliJ  Idea. And upgrade to Java 8 through java 10. This should not be an issue, you are missing files/referenced class modules which are supposed to make your program operate.

Answer (score 1):

This particular class

> oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.taglib.region.RichDeclarativeComponentTag

is part of the ADF Faces Runtime 11 library. Add it up to your project.

Also Make sure to add

> javax.faces.context.ExternalContext

class , which is part of the Java EE 1.5 API library.

Also add JSF 1.2 library to your project.